# Galaxy store app certificate from google play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, samsung-galaxy, galaxy-apps

I have an application on the play store. ( package id : com.ex.exampleapp )

I wanted to put this application on the galaxy store.

The review process on galaxy store, ended by telling me :

"Application uses copyrighted materials without permission owned by a third party.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ex.exampleapp
#Please attach certification file to prove you are the seller of this app."

It is actually my own application on google play store.

**How can I get the certificate from the play store and attach it on the console of the galaxy app store (or inside the app) ?**

Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: It doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

All I did in this case to prove the App is my App, go to your console google play, select your App and take screenshot, that's all.
Attach your screenshot to the review team and resumbit your App.
This worked for me.